# Can we use DBX on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, macos

Can DBX be used to debug live C++ program(keep breakpoint etc) running on Mac OS. (I'm a windows programmer moving to unix platform, trying to setup a development environment on my home machine)

Comment: The OS X development tools come with lldb so I doubt many people have tried, unfortunately.

Comment: you should try gdb or if you code with xcode , you can debug with it.

Comment: @buzz, I'm sure gdb works, but I'm just trying to use the same tool that is used in my workplace which is DBX.

Comment: I know， this isn't a answer, but a suggestion. You move from windows platform, And I move to mac from linux platform ,  so I don't have any problem to fit the platform.  I just think you should use a tool  the platform does well in . Sorry , I have no idea about DBX.